# Change default Sort order for Arcgis Javascript Feature Table

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I would like to have my Feature Table display sorted on the first column when it first appears instead of requiring the user to sort it by clicking on the column header.  I have not been able to find a method to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, it would be nice to be able to set this in the constructor, but if you call `myFeatureTable.grid.set('sort', [{ attribute: ''}]);` after the grid fires it's load event, this will sort it before it appears in the UI.  For example:

```
on(myFeatureTable, "load", function(){
  myFeatureTable.grid.set('sort', [{ attribute: "<attribute used in first column>"}]);
});
```

Another method if you have not required `dojo/on`, you can use the on method of the feature table.

```
myFeatureTable.on('load', function () {
  // Sort on the Name attribute
  myFeatureTable.grid.set('sort', [{ attribute: "Name" }]);
})
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark it.  My map server was down yesterday.  Where would I go to find the documentation for the grid methods?  I couldn't find anything in the ArcGIS JavaScript API site and none of my googles turned up anything.  Is the Feature Table just a Dojo grid so I can use any of the Dojo grid methods?

Comment: It is built on Dojo's dgrid which you can access via myFeatureTable.grid and then use all of the default dgrid api methods.  There is some documentation here for that: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/tree/v1.1.0/doc

Comment: Although it seems their documentation is not the greatest, if you go here (https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.1.0/doc/migrating/API-Comparison.md) you will see hints at the changes from the old dojox/grid that show methods not documented in their new API.  Sometimes it's easier to google/stack overflow dgrid and you'll find things faster.

Answer (score 0):

As I am answering almost 8 years later, I am guessing many things have changed. When configuring a [FeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-featuretable-map/), you can also configure the [FieldColumnTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-FeatureTable-support-FieldColumnTemplate.html), on which one of the properties is "[direction](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-FeatureTable-support-FieldColumnTemplate.html#direction)."

From the documentation:

> Controls the sort order of the column. This property will only be honored on one column in the FeatureTable widget. If direction is specified on more than one fieldColumn in the same FeatureTable, it will only be honored on the column with the highest index. For example, let's say the first column called ObjectId is set to asc and another column later in the table order also has a set direction, the initial ObjectId column's direction will be ignored for the last one with the set direction.

Use this in combination with the `FieldColumnTemplate.initialSortPriority` and `FeatureTable.multiSortEnabled` properties to set sorting functionality for multiple columns."

```js
const fieldColumnTemplate = new FieldColumnTemplate({
  fieldName: "full_name",
  label: "Full name",
  direction: "asc", // In order to use initialSortPriority, make sure direction is set
  initialSortPriority: 0 // This field's sort order takes the highest priority.
});
```

I have used this method and it's working for me (using ArcGIS Javascript API version 4.25).